# Formula that devides date(given in millisecounds)

Tags: divisibility, data-analysis

Just to clarify at the offset, i am a javascript developer and this is a Math question , so my question is as follows:

suppose i create to dates in javascript like so:

var d1 = new Date(2005,12,4); // this will give me the time in millisecounds till '2005,12,4'
var d2 = new Date(2013,05,2); // this will give me the time in millisecounds till '2013,05,2'

now check out the below formula:

```
(d2-d1)/1000/60/60/24/39);
```

note that `d2` and `d1` are both in millisecounds(might look something like `233798400000`) ,

but what is the `/1000/60/60/24/39` for ? What is this formula really giving me in the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division by $1000$ turns milliseconds to seconds, division by $60$ turns seconds into minutes, another division by $60$ turns minutes into hours, division by $24$ turns hours into days, finally division by $39$ turns days into multiples of 39 days (which is not a unit of time any more). So you will end up with the number of 39-day-periods between the dates.

Comment: +1 , but what the heck is 39 LOL , thats been confusing me alot !